# vs code twin page icon disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having difficulties locating my V S Code twin page icon, right below the logo at my upper left. All of the other icons are there, from the searching glass down to the debug icon, but the twin page just vanished. Can someone help me locate it, Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As it stands out, it is unclear what you are asking as you haven't give an image evidence and indication of how the "twin page icon" disappeared. We will not be able to help you with this question unless you revise it and add the evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Please from the top menu, go to:
View > Appearance > Show Activity Bar.